# Avoid adding text to the beginning of the file by calling a function

Tags: function, vim, neovim

I have created a function to be able to add a comment section under some methods. I wrote this in my init file:

```
function! Generate_comments()
    call append(0, '""" ')
    call append(1, 'Description:')
    call append(2, ' ')
    call append(3, 'Args:')
    call append(4, '    param1 (int): desc param1')
    call append(5, '    param2 (str): desc param2')
    call append(6, 'Returns:')
    call append(7, '    returns...')
    call append(8, '""" ')
endfunction
```

assigning it to the mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>cc  :call Generate_comments() <CR>
```

The problem is, that it adds the text to the beginning of the file and not immediately below the line where the cursor is. Could you tell me how to add it correctly under the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

append() works perfectly!

```
function! Generate_comments()
    let snippet = [
        \ '""" ',
        \ 'Description:' ,
        \ ' ',
        \ 'Args:',
        \ '    param1 (int): desc param1',
        \ '    param2 (str): desc param2',
        \ 'Returns:',
        \ '    returns...',
        \ '""" ']
    call append(line('.'), snippet)
endfunction
```